# How to put condition for graph nodes

Tags: java, graph

Is that possible to put condition for nodes in graph like restrict value? 
for example i want to specify that if one node is average, it’s value Couldn’t be more than 20, How to do in Java? thanks a lot.

Comment: We need more details. What type of node, what is the graph design?

Comment: That is a direct graph that display schema of a relational database. Nodes are tables and columns.Restriction is for nodes that display columns.

Comment: I have a vague minimal answer below but you have still not provided enough information. Please post relevant code, a clear explanation of what you are expecting, what you have tried to do, and what problem you are specifically having.

Answer (score 2):

You provide very few details so I will attempt to guess what you are trying to do.

A good and easy way to restrict the value of a field in *any* object is to make sure that all fields are only accessible via getters and setters, and have the setter perform any validation or adjustments. For example, if you want to throw an exception and fail if the value is out of range (replace with whatever exception type you want):

```
public class GraphNode {
    ...
    private float value;

    public float getValue () {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (float value) throws Exception {
        if (value > 20.0f)
            throw new Exception("Value must be <= 20.");
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Or if you just want to silently clamp the value:

```
public class GraphNode {
    ...
    private float value;

    public float getValue () {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (float value) {
        this.value = (value > 20.0f) ? 20.0f : value;
    }

}
```

Then when you change the value:

```
GraphNode node = ...; 
node.setValue(someValue);
```

The logic in `setValue` will ensure that a `GraphNode`'s value is always within the defined constraints.

You can also reuse this logic in a constructor if necessary, e.g. for the first example that throws an exception:

```
public class GraphNode {
    ...

    public GraphNode (float value) throws Exception {
        setValue(value); // throws if out of range
    }

}
```

That way your validation logic is all in one place, and you can set the invariant that no `GraphNode` can exist that violates your constraints (almost, for completeness you'd want to validate after deserialization as well).